# Prevent duplicate insert without unique constraints using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

This is the classical "upsert" problem. I know how to achieve this using pure SQL, but wasn't able to find the equivalent using Entity Framework (v6, code first).

Given the following entity:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Sku { get; set; } // Should be unique

    // Other properties
}
```

I want to create the Save(Product p) method which creates new record if the given Sku does not exist, or updates the existing record if that Sku already exist in the database. The Save method must not create records with duplicate Skus. Also, no unique constraints are defined on the Sku column in the DB.

Checking for duplicates before inserting the record obviously won't work in multi-process environment. I tried wrapping the check in a transaction but that didn't work:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    // if exists, retrieve and update
    // otherwise insert

    db.SaveChanges();
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Any clever ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Use Sku as Key instead of Id  and if there is a duplicate key exception , consider updating it in exception handler instead of trying to add? Add a byte[] Property decorated with [TimeStamp] to use as a concurrencytoken for handling concurrency issues . You will get another exception if data has been already modified where you can handle it and update again.

Comment: @Nish26 Yes, that will work. However this question is specifically about achieving uniqueness without using unique constraints on Sku column (primary key, by definition, is a unique constraint).

Answer (score 2):

If you use Entity Framework 6.1+, `Index` annotation's `IsUnique` property can be used.

In question, you mention `insert without unique constraint`, however, in this `uniqueness` is achieved via code first. I hope this is your want.

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(450)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Sku { get; set; }

    // Other properties
}
```

When I run this code, `SaveChanges` throws `DbUpdateExceptions`as expected.

```
using (DataContext dataContext = new DataContext())
{
    MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass() {Sku = "test1"};
    MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass() {Sku = "test2"};
    MyClass myClass3 = new MyClass() {Sku = "test2"};
    MyClass myClass4 = new MyClass() {Sku = "test3"};

    dataContext.TestTable.Add(myClass1);
    dataContext.TestTable.Add(myClass2);
    dataContext.TestTable.Add(myClass3);
    dataContext.TestTable.Add(myClass4);

    dataContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: As far as I know (and please correct me if I'm wrong), ConcurrencyCheck attribute is only going to affect updates and deletes. In other words, this will not prevent concurrent inserts from inserting duplicates - which is exactly what we want to avoid...

Comment: Yes you right. It is only work for update/delete operations. Difference is that ConcurrencyCheck work for string,int etc. . TimeStamp works only for byte[] (stream) types.  My answer is not valid. Thanks for comment. I search new options :)

Comment: @MilosMrdovic I edit my answer. I hope answer is satisfied you.

Comment: The [Index(IsUnique = true)] attribute creates unique constraint in the database which is exactly what we want to avoid...